# Is there a way to skip bootstrapping drupal to save load time via drush?

Tags: drush

I currently use drush alot to manage my sites, but I was wondering if there was a way to skip bootstrapping drupal everytime drush is run for certain commands that might not need it. This would save significant load time. I tend to do pm-list alot, but sometimes it just takes a long time to load depending on the size of the site. Same goes for enabling/disabling modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is hard-coded for each command: The module defining a Drush command sets the bootstrap level required to run the command. For example, [cache_drush_command()](http://api.drush.org/api/drush/commands!core!cache.drush.inc/function/cache_drush_command/5.x) defines cache-clear as the following:

```
  $items['cache-clear'] = array(
    'bootstrap' => DRUSH_BOOTSTRAP_MAX, 
    'description' => 'Clear a specific cache, or all drupal caches.', 
    'arguments' => array(
      'type' => 'The particular cache to clear. Omit this argument to choose from available caches.',
    ), 
    'callback' => 'drush_cache_command_clear', 
    'aliases' => array('cc'),
  );
```

To require not bootstrap at all, the "bootstrap" property should be defined as follows.

```
  $items['xkcd-fetch'] = array(
    'description' => "Retrieve and display xkcd cartoons.", 
    'arguments' => array(
      'search' => 'Optional argument to retrive the cartoons matching an index number, keyword search or "random". If omitted the latest cartoon will be retrieved.',
    ), 
    'options' => array(
      'image-viewer' => 'Command to use to view images (e.g. xv, firefox). Defaults to "display" (from ImageMagick).', 
      'google-custom-search-api-key' => 'Google Custom Search API Key, available from https://code.google.com/apis/console/. Default key limited to 100 queries/day globally.',
    ), 
    'examples' => array(
      'drush xkcd' => 'Retrieve and display the latest cartoon.', 
      'drush xkcd sandwich' => 'Retrieve and display cartoons about sandwiches.', 
      'drush xkcd 123 --image-viewer=eog' => 'Retrieve and display cartoon #123 in eog.', 
      'drush xkcd random --image-viewer=firefox' => 'Retrieve and display a random cartoon in Firefox.',
    ), 
    'aliases' => array('xkcd'), 
    'bootstrap' => DRUSH_BOOTSTRAP_DRUSH, // No bootstrap at all.
  );
```

Using `DRUSH_BOOTSTRAP_DRUSH` says to Drush that Drupal doesn't need to be bootstrapped at all.

Clearly, that is not something that can be arbitrarily changed; it depends from the code executed from the command.

Comment: IOW, drush uses the minimal bootstrap necessary for the task it is trying to accomplish.